# How to trace a recursive make?

Tags: makefile, trace, recursion

I need to work on a system that uses automake tools and makes recursively.

'make -n' only traces the top level of make.

Is there a way to cause make to execute a make -n whenever he encounters a make command?

Answer (score 3):

Use `$(MAKE)` to call your submakefiles, instead of using `make`.  That should work.  Check out [How the `MAKE` variable works](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#MAKE-Variable) in the manual.  Here's a quick example:

Makefile:

```
all:
    @$(MAKE) -f Makefile2
```

Makefile2:

```
all:
    @echo Makefile2
```

Command line:

```
$ make
Makefile2
$ make -n
make -f Makefile2
echo Makefile2
$
```

Answer (score 3):

Does your recursive makefile look like this:

```
foo:
    make -C src1
    make -C src2
```

Or like this:

```
foo:
    ${MAKE} -C src1
    ${MAKE} -C src2
```

I think you need to use the second style if you want flags passed to child make processes.  Could be your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the environment variable "MAKEFLAGS" to "n" may do what you need.

There are some more advanced tricks for tracing make commands here:
http://www.cmcrossroads.com/ask-mr-make/6535-tracing-rule-execution-in-gnu-make

The simplest of these tricks comes down to adding SHELL="sh -x" to your make command (running without "-n" in that case).